# Get distinct values of a vector and keep the order

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to get the distinct values of a vector of real numbers and keep their order. For example:
[1, -1, 5, -1] -> [1, -1, 5]. What I did so far:

```
std::vector<double> getDistinctValues(const std::vector<double>& data)
{
    std::unordered_set<double> distinct(data.begin(), data.end());
    std::vector<double> result(distinct.begin(), distinct.end());

    return result;
}
```

This solution doesn't keep the order.

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) or `std::unique_copy`

Comment: When you have a need like this, hunt through a reference to see what pieces of the puzzle the standard library might provide. Do some research!

Comment: Are the multiple values in the vector *consecutive* or can they appear in any order (e.g. [1, -1, 5, -1])? The library functions proposed so far require those to be consecutive.

Comment: The repeating values can appear in any order, not only consecutively!

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
std::vector<double> sort(const std::vector<double>& data) {
  std::vector<double> result;
  std::unique_copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
  return result;
}
```

N.B.: I wouldn't name a function `sort` when that function's explicit goal is to preserve the order of elements.

Comment: You could take by value and use `unique` then `erase`. That lets the caller run this on an existing vector without _any_ copies if they want. Yours mandates at least one.

Comment: Please note that this solution requires the copies to be consecutive.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't taking a parameter by value require a copy, no matter what happens inside the function?

Comment: @Bob__ Ah. The example given at the time of writing did have consecutive duplicates. The question was edited after I wrote the answer. However, with non-consecutive duplicates, I'm not sure what "keep their order" means.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, the caller can write `sort(std::move(myVector))`. Your version prohibits making use of move semantics in that way.